# Is it possible to overclock a 2011 i7 macbook pro

Tags: macos, mac, osx-mountain-lion, overclocking

I am just wondering if it is possible to overclock a 2011 i7 2.4 macbook pro? Either with software or if there is other ways of doing it.

Comment: `Mac` and `overclock` are 2 words very uncommonly seen together for a reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, and even if there was you shouldn't do it on an Apple Laptop.  They don't have sufficient cooling as it is (restricted airflow, sleek design and good cooling are somewhat mutually exclusive), so Apple tends to actually underclock them until the system says it's imperative.  (A cooling pad would help, but still possibly dangerous in the OC process).

Either way, the CPU clock and voltages are hard-coded by the EFI (Comparable to the "Bios", but very locked down).

Now in Windows on a Mac, you could overclock the GPU.  But that isn't the substance of your question.

Comment: It would be great if there was some software out there that allowed something like this.

Comment: @Stephen Don't buy a mac next time, then you don't have Steve Jobs telling you how to use your computer!

Comment: LOL, I will have to give that some thought!